# Append new data to Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, append

Im making an app that shows images from an `tumblr` account. It shows 20 images a time, and at the bottom there is a botten that when pressed should load 20 new images to the list (only showing the new 20 images). Im using `AsyncTask` to execute the process. I have come quite far but when the "load more" botton is clicked the app crashes with a `NullPointerException` at the line: `tumblrs.add(tumblr);` within the `DoInBackground` class. I can´t seem to find the problem and is stuck at this point.

The code looks like this:

```
public class Example extends Activity {

ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;
Context context = null;
ListView listView = null;
TextView footer;
int offset = 0;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

private String searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset=0";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;
    try {
        tumblrs = getTumblrs();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null);
        footer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFoot);
        listView.addFooterView(v);
        listView.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem,
                tumblrs));

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    footer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new loadMoreListView().execute();
        }
    });

}

public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tumblr> {
    private ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int imageViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs) {
        super(context, imageViewResourceId, tumblrs);
        this.tumblrs = tumblrs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

        }

        Tumblr tumblr = tumblrs.get(position);
        if (tumblr != null) {

            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);

            if (image != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(tumblr.image_url));
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                .getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Tumblr> getTumblrs() throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, JSONException {
    searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset=0";

    ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs = new ArrayList<Tumblr>();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    String responseBody = null;
    try {
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

    JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray(
            "posts");
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("photos");
        for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
            String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes").getJSONObject(0)
                    .getString("url");

            Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
            tumblrs.add(tumblr);
        }
    }
    return tumblrs;
}

public class Tumblr {

    public String image_url;

    public Tumblr(String url) {

        this.image_url = url;
    }
}

private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Example.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // increment current page
                offset += 20;

                // Next page request

                searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset="
                        + offset;

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

                String responseBody = null;
                try {
                    responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

                    JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response")
                            .getJSONArray("posts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getJSONArray("photos");
                        for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
                            String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes")
                                    .getJSONObject(0).getString("url");

                            Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
                            tumblrs.add(tumblr);

                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll
                // position
                int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                // Setting new scroll position
                listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

}
```

Help is highly appriciated.

Comment: Start by checking the value of the `tumblrs` reference. Very likely it is `null`.

Comment: And read the stack trace of the exception. It tells where in the code the exception is thrown. You didn't gave us this information.

Comment: Also, Why does your doInBackground method does nothing other than running a task in the UI thread? What's the point of a background task which executes in the foreground?

Comment: Notice that you haven't initialized your tumblers in your loadMoreListView class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be failing to initialize your field "tumblrs" (declared in line 3) in your onCreate method as you redeclared it as a local variable in line 17.

Comment: Thansk for the help. Now it works, by appending to the list. Do you have a simple solution, if i want the list to only show the 20 new images, and not the previous 20 at the same time?

Comment: I guess you could add another field to the "Tumblr" class, something like "public boolean isNew". Then, when you build the list, only add the ones where this flag is set. Or, if the new ones always end up at the end of "tumblrs", simply only add the last 20 elements to the listbox. There's many ways to do this and which one is best depends on your definition of "new" and what else you would like to do with your list later.

Answer (score 1):

The `tumblrs` field is not initialized. In the onCreate method, you initialize a **local** variable also named `tumblrs`.